# quantile regression for unbalanced panel data in R

Tags: panel-data, quantile-regression

I am using Canay's R [program](http://sites.northwestern.edu/iac879/files/2014/06/QR-2Step-2bji2ci.zip) to explore quantile regression for panel data. In the example given, Grunfeld data is used. Following the Example.R file everything goes smoothly. However, when I delete some rows to create an unbalanced panel from the Grunfeld data I obtain errors. I am using the following command to remove some rows.

```
Grunfeld <- Grunfeld[-c(190:194),]
```

I wonder if it is not possible to use any unbalanced panel data with [Canay's two step](http://sites.northwestern.edu/iac879/files/2014/06/SimpleQRpanel_EJ-192ro74.pdf) approach. Could you point me into the right direction on how to conduct a quantile regression with unbalanced panel data on R.